# How do I update the presence of my Discord bot every like 5 minutes?

Tags: discord.js

I am making a Discord bot using Discord.js V12, and I want to get it to display how many members (as a status/presence) are in a server but I can't get it to update how many members are in the server. How would I go about doing that? Here is the code I have so far:

It just won't detect when someone else joins the server unless I restart the bot.

```
  const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('848109201901617193');
  const activities = [
    `over ${guild.memberCount - 7} members.`,
    `over ${guild.memberCount - 7} members.`
  ]
  setInterval(() => {
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (activities.length - 1));
    const newActivity = activities[randomIndex];

    client.user.setActivity(newActivity, { type: 'WATCHING' });
  }, 10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

The string needs to be updated each time you want to set the status.

```
setInterval(async () => {
    const guild = await client.guilds.fetch('848109201901617193', true, true);

    const newActivity = `over ${guild.memberCount - 7} members.`;
    client.user.setActivity(newActivity , { type: 'WATCHING' });
}, 5 * 60 * 1000);
```

Note: If you have the Guild members intent `client.guilds.fetch('848109201901617193')` or `..cache.get(..` is fine too!

Alternative you could update the Status on the `guildMemberAdd` Event.

Answer (score 0):

```js
client.on("ready", () => {
console.log("ready");
//...
client.user.setActivity(); //... put activity
});

client.on("guildMemberAdd", member => {
client.user.setActivity() //... same thing
})
//and do the same with guild member remove
```

Comment: Thanks, but I keep on getting an error saying this:

```/home/runner/Plexbot/index.js:52
      name: `over ${guild.memberCount - 8} members.`,
          ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'```

Comment: Maybe you forgot the {}s?

Answer (score -1):

Your guild details are cache so that `memberCount` even discord API updated it. Add discord also slow update on this properties not update immediately when member join guild. And there is no need to random activities there.

So you need to fetch new guild details code will be:

```js
  setInterval(async () => {
  const guild = await client.guilds.fetch('848109201901617193', true, true);
  const newActivity = `over ${guild.memberCount - 7} members.`;
    client.user.setActivity(newActivity , { type: 'WATCHING' });
  }, 10000);
```

Docs for fetch new guild [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildManager?scrollTo=fetch)